# Preg_replace in php for a specified construction

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have a problem with my preg_replace. I need to do this for a string who contains more @..@, For example I have :

```
@CN@ This is a test. Big test @DATE@ and @DATE_END@.
```

Now I want to get a list with :

My code:

```
$pattern = '/@[_a-zA-Z0-9]*@/';
preg_match_all($pattern,'',$aData[$i]['tags']);
@CN@,@DATE@,@DATE_END@
```

Between @...@ can be multiple expressions.

Comment: Post an example of those *multiple expressions*, and also post your attempt at solving this issue, even if it doesn't work.

Comment: I don't get it. You're talking about `preg_replace()` but in the code you're using `preg_match_all()`. Could you be a bit clear by improving the question.

Answer (score 1):

Use `preg_match_all` with `implode` function.

```
$str = "@CN@ This is a test. Big test @DATE@ and @DATE_END@.";
preg_match_all('/@[^@]*@/', $str, $match);
echo implode(",", $match[0]);
```

The above implode function helps to join the array elements with comma as delimiter.

Output:

```
@CN@,@DATE@,@DATE_END@
```

Comment: Use `@\w*@` regex if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to use preg_match_all instead:

```
preg_match_all('/(@[^@]+@)/', $input, $match)
```